# sed substitute not working after sed print

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to do a substitution on a set of printed lines from my maillog.
I want to find the lines then just strip out the address. All I am getting is the printed lines as it seems like it is ignoring the follow up substitution command here is the example.

```
sed -n -e '/username/p' -e 's/^.*\(to=.*\.org>\).*$/\1/' /var/log/maillog
```

The lines I want show up but I want the to email address out of the log entries.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Since you never print anything after the `s///` operation, you can't tell whether it does anything or not — it does, but you don't see the result because you never write it to the output.

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean:

```
sed -n -e '/username/{ s/^.*\(to=.*\.org>\).*$/\1/; p; }' /var/log/maillog
```

First it would find a line with `username` on it, substitute some strings (`s`), then print (`p`).

And maybe this one's synonymous:

```
sed -n -e '/username/s/^.*\(to=.*\.org>\).*$/\1/p' /var/log/maillog
```

Comment: or `sed -n -e '/username/!d' -e 's/^.*\(to=.*\.org>\).*$/\1/p'`

Comment: Yes that is what works.  That second version is very simple and elegant.  I never thought to combine the substitute and print together.